# On Travis CI listing of GItHub projects, can I hide forks?

Tags: travis-ci

I'm adding Travis CI to several little projects, as I scan the list I'd like to not see meaningless forks I have laying around.

Answer (score 1):

There doesn't seem to be a way. This isn't a big issue though (unless you have 100 forks and only a few real repositories..)